# JavaMail - Having issues with Attachement when executing from Tomcat on Linux server

Tags: tomcat, exception, jakarta-mail, attachment

I have written a simple code to send email with single attachement. This works fine when I am testing it on my machine. But when I deploy it on Linux server in Tomcat I get below "File not found Exception". Another issue is that I am not seeing the entire path of the files getting attached. i.e. I was expecting  C:\temp\btbc.info NOT btbc.info.

ataching filebtbc.info
Caugth Messaging Exceptionjavax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: btbc.info (No such file or directory)

My Frontend code

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Email Hotline</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="external/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Internal Reference -->
<link href="internal/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- External Reference -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald"
rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Email </h1>
        <p>Test Email Service</p>
        <br>

        <a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Notify
            Fraud</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="myEmail" role="form" method="POST" action="notify.do">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Send Email</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usrTxt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea name="usrTxt" id="usrTxt" class="form-control"
                                rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file-upload" class="col-sm-2 control-label">File
                            upload</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="file" name="attachFile" class="form-control"
                                id="file-upload" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="sndButton" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="external/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
<!--// Form validation code will come here.-->

    function validateText(id) {
        //var input = $("#"+id).val(); 


        if( $("#"+id).val() == "" || $("#"+id).val() == null  ) {
            var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
            div.addClass("has-error");
            return false;
        } else {
            var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
            div.removeClass("has-error");
            return true;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(

    function() {
        $("#sndButton").click(function() {
            if (!validateText("usrTxt")) {
                return false;
            }

            $("form#myEmail").submit();
        });
    }

    );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

and my Java code.

```
package com.service.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class FraudEmail {

public boolean notify(String content, String attachFile) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;


    String fromAddress;
    String recipients;
    String subject;
    String contentType = "text/html";

    try {
        input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/mail.properties");

        if (input != null) {
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file mail.properties not found in the classpath");
        }

        fromAddress = prop.getProperty("from");
        recipients = prop.getProperty("to");
        subject = prop.getProperty("subject");

        Session session = null;
        try {

            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            session = (Session) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/mail/Session");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

        message.setSubject(subject);            
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates body part for the message
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(content, contentType);                                

        // creates multi-part         
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        if (attachFile != null && attachFile.length() > 0) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            try {
                System.out.println("ataching file" +attachFile);
                attachPart.attachFile(attachFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }               

        // sets the multipart as message's content
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(message);

        return true;
    } catch (MessagingException messagingException) {
        System.out.print("Caugth Messaging Exception");
        System.out.print(messagingException);
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Caugth Exception");
        System.out.print(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Who calls the "notify" method and where does the "attachFile" come from?  Is the file being uploaded from the browser to the server?  Where is the file being stored?

Comment: "notify.do" is mapped to a servlet and the mapping is defined in web.xml. attachFile variable gets its value from HttpSerlvetRequest.    String attachment = request.getParameter("attachFile"); and the files that is being attached is from my windows machine for testing purpose.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're uploading the file from the browser machine to the server machine.  Just having the name of a file on your browser machine isn't going to let you access the file on the server machine.

Comment: Thank you Bill, but is there a way to identify if anything is blocking the uploading of files..

Comment: Um, debugging?  How exactly are you uploading the files?  It doesn't happen just by magic, you have to write code that does it.